# querySelectorAll with a dynamic parameter

Tags: javascript

I would like to use `querySelectorAll()` with a dynamic parameter.

This is what I have tried:

```js
const titleEnabled = (document.getElementById('enable-title').checked) ? '.mt-title' : '';
const storenameEnabled = (document.getElementById('enable-storename').checked) ? '.mt-storename' : '';
const dynamicEnabled = (document.getElementById('enable-dynamic').checked) ? '.mt-dynamic' : '';

const query = titleEnabled + comma(titleEnabled) + storenameEnabled + comma(storenameEnabled, dynamicEnabled) + dynamicEnabled;
console.log('Query: ' + query);

if (titleEnabled || storenameEnabled || dynamicEnabled) {
    const mtCategories = document.querySelectorAll(query);
}

// Return a comma 
const comma = (...arr) => {
    for (let a of arr) {
    if (a !== '') {
        return ', '
    }
    return '';
  }
}
```

But this is the error that I get:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '.mt-storename, ' is not a valid selector.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You can't have a comma at the end of the selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work well.

```
const titleEnabled = (document.getElementById('enable-title').checked) ? '.mt-title' : '';
const storenameEnabled = (document.getElementById('enable-storename').checked) ? '.mt-storename' : '';
const dynamicEnabled = (document.getElementById('enable-dynamic').checked) ? '.mt-dynamic' : '';


const arr = [];
[titleEnabled, storenameEnabled, dynamicEnabled].forEach((item) => {
  if (item) {
    arr.push(item);
  }
});

const query = arr.join(", ");
console.log("Query: " + query);
document.querySelectorAll(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I could do it without any errors:

```
  const titleEnabled = (document.getElementById('enable-title').checked) ? '.mt-title' : '';
  const storenameEnabled = (document.getElementById('enable-storename').checked) ? '.mt-storename' : '';
  const dynamicEnabled = (document.getElementById('enable-dynamic').checked) ? '.mt-dynamic' : '';

  let query = '';
  if (titleEnabled) {
    query = titleEnabled;
    if (storenameEnabled || dynamicEnabled) {
      query += ', ';
    }
  }
  if (storenameEnabled) {
    query += storenameEnabled;
    if (dynamicEnabled) {
      query += ', ';
    }
  }
  if (dynamicEnabled) {
    query += dynamicEnabled;
  }
   console.log('Query: ' + query);
  if (query) {
    const mtCategories = document.querySelectorAll(query); 
  }
```

But I prefer the solution from Yevhenii Shlapak.